# How should i start with PHP zend framework OOP based website

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop, zend-framework

I want to build a website having these things

1. PHP5 or above
2. Zend Framework
3. Purely Object oriented
4. Unit testing
5. Agile Methodology
6. ORM

I have to submit one project as a website using above features. I know PHP for about 5 years but not in OOP and i have made many joomla/php/mysql/jquery websites.
I know the basics of spring/hibernate/annotations/spring MVC/java but not advanced level

So I want to know what sort of website i can build which can have those features. If there is any book or tutorial , please provide the link so that i can start. i have 6 months time

Comment: Actually i read but was confused with oop concepts. is there any alternative of ZEND which is pure OOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial does introduce many concepts in rapid succession (multiple setups for dev-stage-prod, routing , and much more) within just  a few pages.I found it dizzying 2 years ago when I peeked into it, maybe it's changed since then. On the other hand, I am quite fond of their component documentation, but the api section section could be improved.

I think you could pull this off, full oop, quite easily with a few Zend components.  I have  never as of yet used the full Zend_App stack, but instead have been happily using Zend components in 3/4 of my projects for the past year.  All OOP, I just don't use (and don't need) their full-blown mvc implementation.

The components as stand-alone are easy enough to comprehend and use, I basically go for Zend_Config, Zend_Mail, Zend_Db, Zend_Table, Zend_Statement,  Zend_Load, Zend_Log and Zend_Pdf when printable stuff is needed. I have found  that just these minimal classes give me a good base to kick-off whatever problem I attack without having to re-invent the wheel.

There are other lightweight mvc frameworks out there, but in my humble opinion if you attack will Zend you will learn the basics of a commonly used library, used in a lot of companies.

My 2 cents, good-luck to you!